# Proof of Financial Means for Fees

Tags: visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, fees-and-charges, student-visas

If one has been awarded a scholarship for studying in Spain providing 600 euros every month starting in October for seven months and if one has paid only the first installment of university fees and the second one is due in January, will they need to show this amount of fee in proof of financial means for visa application?

The scholarship does not cover university fees.